# How do I create an irregular 7 side object

Tags: edit-mode

I want to create a mesh object which has 7 sides but each side is not the same length as the others.
Consider the following satellite image which I have marked in red. The approximate lengths of each side are also marked in red.
I thought perhaps the answer is to create a start with a cylinder, set vertices to 7 and then drag the vertices but it seems messy and perhaps there is an easy method I have not though of.
Or maybe a cube and add vertices then drag them out. What is the easiest solution?
The object I want to create is actually the end of a concrete dock.
I want to try and keep each side approximately the same as indicated (in meters), The left and right sides are parallel.
[Added later]
I have tried creating a cube with dimensions of 15 X 13.5 and thickness (Z) of 0.15 then in edit mode 'add vertice' (ctrl R) then select an 'edge' on the 'thin' side and dragging it (G Y) but do not know how to end up with the sides of a length I require.

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible way would be to start with just vertices.

So if you have a cube, go to edit mode, M -> merge at center. Now you have 1 vertex. Press E (extrude), the x 15, then E y 13, then e y 6.5 G X 6.5 ...see?

If you have the whole outline

[image]

select all and press F.

[image]

then E and move your mouse and you have geometry.

Comment: Oopy you where a bit faster, should i remove my post or keep the "edge lenght" info in it?

Comment: @EvripidisLalissidis I would keep it in, because the last sentence in the question ends with "but do not know how to end up with the sides of a length I require", and actually just moving(extruding on the axes when you don't know how far wouldn't get you the correct result without edge lengths.

Comment: That looks ok but how to extrude NOT along the X or Y axis eg if extrude required at a 45 degree angle?

Comment: as i wrote here (but i didn't explain): "e y 6.5 G X 6.5" -> this extrudes to y 6.5 and then moves (G x) 6.5 (sorry, i wrote it wrong and too fast - i corrected this, forgot the x and somehow the 4 was pressed too much)

Comment: Thanks Chris.  So there is no method to enter an exact value in degrees? -calculate the distance to extrude and move? Easy if its 45 degrees as each movement would be the same but anything else would need calculation. I hope understood you correctly.  I guess with the model I am trying to create dimensions don't have to be exact.

Comment: @JohnArnold: AFAIK - no. But there might be add-ons somewhere which can do this...and tbh....it shouldn't be too hard developing such an add-on ;)

Comment: @Chris I also meant to ask how you complete/finish creating the multli-sided object.  For example  extrude/move (point) A to B to C to D to E to F and then back to A (the starting point). I am thinking it could be difficult doing it 'freehand' Just be careful?

Comment: @Chris  VERY EASY when you know how. I now have my 'concrete slab' outlined (see attached to original question).

Comment: @JohnArnold: That's with (nearly) all things in life: if you know how, it's easy ;) But if you don't know - it seems impossible. I am not sure what you meant with "finish". If you extruded all points, you should have a closed edge loop. Then select all, press F to get the middle face and press E to extrude upwards (if you want that).

Comment: @chris  All is good now. As I worked out the lengths of every edge calculating some as triangles I ended up exactly in line with the start point and exactly the correct distance so just had to enter E X -13.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single vertices as a way to build the foundation.

- Using "Shift + A," add a plane.
- Enter edit mode.
- To enter vertices mode, press 1 on your keyboard.
- To select everything, press A.
- Press M and select "at center" to merge them all into a single vertice.
- Now, select your vertices in the center and extrude them until you have the final shape.

[image]

You can use XYZ to constrain the movement, and at the top left of your screen while extruding or moving, you can see the increments.

Also, a very handy trick is to use "edge length" information to make your life a lot easier via the "Viewport overlay.".

[image]

Comment: I have 'resurrected' this thread as I am having trouble with a NEW mesh crated using this method. When I apply a texture image material the mesh goes black on all faces and the texture image is not seen (viewport shading IS on). I am starting with a 'blank canvas' and started with a NEW mesh cube so no material is attached. Any ideas why this is happening and what to do to fix it?   [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1abgKXpJ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1abgKXpJ/)