# How to remove internal faces and edges and add edges to intersecting meshes

Tags: edit-mode

I have created all the external walls of a building using intersecting rectangle, octagon and hexagon meshes to replicate a real building with many different walls at different angles (see image below). Being new to such complexity I could not think of any other method to replicate to walls on a real building I want to model.

Even joining all the meshes I end up with an object with heaps of internal edges and no edges where meshes have intersected which will make application of my material (for the wall panelling)  and adding bevel at corners to add ‘timber framing’ to these edges (see green ‘framing’ in same image) very difficult.
I thought that I could create a new mesh (cube or plane) large enough to cover the base of my ‘object’ and then use the Boolean modifier set to Intersect to create a new mesh (cube or plane) the same shape as the base of my building but could not get that to work.

I also considered creating a new mesh by starting with a single vertex and then extruding along the outside edges of my building base as a template (refer [how to create an irregular multisided  mesh object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279835/how-do-i-create-an-irregular-7-side-object)) but wondered if there is an quicker method.

I just want a multifaced mesh of the exterior of the building.

I have attached a blender file of the building.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Walls with panelling and trim (materials) added]

Comment: No wonder that "even joining all the meshes" didn't help. If you mean the _Join selected objects into active object_ function (Ctrl+J), it's like having a model kit and throwing the pieces into a bag. Now they are all together, you can move them by just carrying a single bag, but the model will not be assembled just because you throw the pieces in the same bag. At first I would clean up your mesh. The top and bottom faces of the pieces are not even the same height. Maybe scale them to 0 on Z axis. Or use snapping - also for the corners, many of them are not flush.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Firstly I had noticed that some the top and bottom faces on some meshes are not aligned but have no idea as every mesh I added had the same height (z axis) and the same origin. When I attempted to correct it I used snapping (tried face and also edge) and could not get them to 'snap' together. I do not know how to 'scale them to 0 on the Z axis). Also how to snap them. I was hoping that I could use the building and a plane with boolean to create a shape the same as the outside walls of the building but couldn't get that to0 work either.

Comment: maybe it would be easier to start again but what method should I use to create a building with so many different walls at different angles to adjacent ones?

Comment: FYI I have started to create a new object using the original object as a template, adding a mesh cube (resized accordingly), using Extrude and making minor adjustments using G before proceeding to the next section of the 'floor plan'. It seems to be working and won't take long.

Comment: Scale to 0 on the Z axis: press `S` `Z` `0` and left-click or hit `Return` to confirm the scale. And snapping works too, I would use vertex snapping...  can't tell in which way you might have done it wrong. I already suggested months ago, please make yourself familiar with the basic modeling techniques, watch tutorials and practice with simple objects instead of trying to build complex scenes with lots of special objects. How can it be that you have no idea how to scale up or down to a certain value on a certain axis? Please learn the basics.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. With respect I have lost count on the number of  Youtube video tutorials I have watched and would maybe watch at least 3 every day. I ALWAYS look for youtube tutorials before posting a question here - I only reply on blender exchange when I can't find answers elsewhere.  Thanks for the tip regarding basic modelling tips and just 'googled' that and got a number of hits. Also there must be literally hundreds of commands, tools etc etc in Blender and I keep 'chipping' at them learning new ones regularly and making notes for reference. Practice makes perfect (sometimes).

Comment: Also  "How can it be that you have no idea how to scale up or down to a certain value on a certain axis?"  I have always used the transform 'box' (dimensions) to change the size on a particular axis and then 'apply' scale. Not sure why one would use scale instead of using the transform box especially when you want (say) a certain dimension eg 5.15 meters. Using scale I would have to use a calculator to work out changing a 2 meter length to 5.15 meters  = scale 2.575

Comment: I have completed the task as I initially asked if it was the best or only solution. Firstly to make it easier I set the Z axis to 0 for all meshes as has been suggested. I then used the resulting 'plane' as a template and added another plane to one edge and sized it. Then using Extrude (with edge selected) I dragged the edge to the next vertex (this was easy when on the X or Y axis and slightly difficult when not). I used G to make minor adjustments.. Within about 10 minutes it was complete and I posted an image in the original question. I then added a solidify modify to give all the walls